# Obtain HTML between two tags using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tags, flat

**Set Up**

I'm using Selenium to obtain a set of links on a page.

The page HTML structure is 'flat'; no indentations, no children, etc. and looks like,

```
 <h2>TAG1</h2>
 <a href...>...</a>
 'more links'
 <a href...>...</a>
 <h2>TAG2</h2>
```

---

**Problem**

The links I want to obtain are located between (**not** inside) the two `h2` tags.

How do I tell selenium to obtain the HTML (or directly the links) between `TAG1` and `TAG2`?

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the `outerHTML` possibly till the parent tag of `<h2>` tag?

Comment: Ha Jeff, my bad: next time I'll link to all the unrelated stuff I found on SO and plug it inside the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This xpath should do the trick

```
//a[./preceding-sibling::h2[.='TAG1']][./following-sibling::h2[.='TAG2']]
```

The xpath reads as select all a tags which has h2 with text TAG 1 preceding it and h2 with text TAG2 following it.

Answer (score 3):

this css selector should works `h2 ~ a`
example: (in python)

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h2 ~ a')
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in elements]
```

Comment: Super clean and understandable locator. No need for all the XPath complexity here.

Comment: `h2 ~ a` will list all the `a` siblings of `h2`. It does not answer the original question of selecting siblings between 2 tags.